# How to use C libraries in Delphi using SWIG wrap

Tags: c, delphi, dll, swig

I have a Delphi file generated by SWIG (.pas) and a _wrap.c file also generated by SWIG. I compiled the C code to .dll library and i would like to use files generated by swig in my Delphi project. Could anyone tell me how to do this? I have to compile the _wrap.c file or the .pas file? Or maybe link to my project?

Comment: Can you show both the pas file and the _wrap.c file?

Comment: You cannot compile C code in Delphi, so you can't compile the `_wrap.c` file. You need to provide more details about the .pas file in order for us to tell you what to do with it. Most likely you need to add it to the `uses` clause in the unit where you're going to call the DLL functions.

Comment: If you are using the Delphi version of SWIG by FMXExpress, you can build the their examples and see how to compile the generated source - flags and options